# Regex to extract sport score

Tags: regex

I have string values with the follow pattern

```
"Buffalo Bill's 14, NewYork Giants 24 Final"
```

My goal is to capture each team name and the corresponding score and game status with regex

1. Buffalo Bill's
2. 14
3. NewYork Giants
4. 24
5. Final

I tried the following, but this only got me the team and score combined.

```
(?<Score>[\w\s']+\s\d+)
```

Comment: If there are 5 parts and the digits and comma are always there, maybe  `^(\w.*?) (\d+), (\w.*?) (\d+) (\w.*)` https://regex101.com/r/7aMQBm/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern that you tried matches the team and the score combined because the character class `[\w\s']+` also matches a whitespace `\s` and `\w` can also match a digit.

If there are always 5 parts and the digits and the comma are always present, for the first and the third part you could start the match with a word character (Or `\S` to match a non whitespace char) and then match as least chars as possible till the next encounter of a space and 1+ digits.

For the second and fourth part, you can capture 1+ digits and for the fifth part start the match again with a word character followed by the rest of the line or just `\w+` to only match Final.

```
^(\w.*?) (\d+), (\w.*?) (\d+) (\w.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7aMQBm/1)